# Filter table rows with jquery

Tags: jquery, filter, row

I would like to know how to filter table rows based on a column value. Plugins excluded, I would like to figure it out how to make this thing to work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but the general idea would be something like this:

```
$("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().indexOf("whatever") !== -1;
}).parent().remove();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/xQB4Z/). It first selects all table cells, then filters them based on some text, and removes the parent (which should be the `tr`) of any remaining rows.

If you don't care about individual columns, you can select the `tr` elements and get rid of the call to `parent`. That will still work because `text` will return the text of all the children of the selected `tr`.

**Update** based on comments

The above will remove the matching table rows from the DOM completely. If you want to just hide them, you can replace `remove` with `hide`. If you then wanted to make the rows visible again you could simply do something like:

```
$("tr").show();
```

Which selects all the `tr` elements and shows them (ones that are already visible will not be affected, so just the ones previously hidden will become visible again).

Comment: will this work with .hide() as well? in case it is possible, what would be a good way to show /unhide all table rows in case i want to reset the filter?

Answer (score 19):

Here's another example of filtering table rows.  Turning the filter value and the table row text lowercase makes the filter case insensitive.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#filter").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#example-table > tbody > tr").filter(function() {      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="filter">Filter:</label> <input type="text" id="filter">
  </div>
  <table id="example-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenny</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>51</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mike</td>
        <td>Smithers</td>
        <td>52</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea behind all table-filtering is to hide all rows and then show those where the content of a `<td>` has the searchstring included.

With jQuery the magic is done like this:

```
$('tr').filter(":contains('" + searchstring + "')").show();
```

But there's no need to use jQuery for this - I've coded a plain JS-solution for it. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/StephanWeinhold/8d2cbe1787f4b46944e5).