# jQuery filter table by keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I've been searching for all kinds of solution and the filter table
 still doesn't work. That's why I've decided to post up the codes to
 see what's wrong.

My table result is extracted from database.

HTML

```
<h3>Members</h3>
    <c:if test="${!empty memberList}">
    <table id="example" class="data">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <form:form name="membersearch" id="search" modelAttribute="member" method="post" action="${searchMemberURL}" >
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="keyword">Keyword: </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="keyword" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="searchby">Search By: </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="searchby" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form:form>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Below is my javascript for jquery keyword search

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $rows = $('#example tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: btw, spaces are not allowed in the id attribute.. is this (`id="search "`) a typo?

Comment: Hi, thanks for correcting me. Yes it's a typo.

Comment: where did you put jquery event key up,`<input type='textfield' id='search'>` in your code? are trying to achieve filter/search via event keyup or submit button

Comment: trying to achieve via submit button actually. Users will key in keyword in the textbox, then click search to filter only the result. However I don't mind to alter how the search works as long i can filter the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter table rows with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951014/filter-table-rows-with-jquery)