# Search for value in column then filter table after matched results

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table, match

**What I am trying to achieve**

***Short:*** Search for value in column then filter table after matched results

I got **HTML** buttons which has a value defined.
At the click of the button, pass the value to the string: `value` then search the first column for the value, match the value with the column's content and hide the ones that does not match.

I want to achieve this with jQuery.

**My problem**

I seem to be stuck on how to search the specific column and how to match it with the string `value`. I am using a `pseudo` selector to find the column.
*I hide all the non-matches.*

*The line that is supposed to handle this:*

```
$(this).toggle("td:nth-child(1)").text().toLowerCase().includes(value);
```

**Code and DOM**

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" id="res_btn" value="R" class="btn btn-light">Research</button>
```

*jQuery*

```
$('#res_btn').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#table tr:not(:has(th))').filter(function() {
        //line im struggling with   
        $(this).toggle("td:nth-child(1)").text().toLowerCase().includes(value);
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

I've been trying to search for similar questions for ages but none generally apply to mine. However, if you find other questions that might have the same type of problem, please link it.

Comment: Check the documentation on the different methods you're using ([`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/), [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/), [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)). Looks like you didn't quite understand what they were doing.

Comment: Please post your `table` code

Comment: @Andreas Definitely, the right methods are something I would need guidance with. I've tried several alternatives but can't find the right combination. `.toggle()` is what I use to toggle the visibility of the row. `.text()` is what I use to get the text contents of the column. However I am unsure of `.includes()`.

Comment: `.toggle("td:nth-child(1)")` won't "toggle" the row. And anything after that is more or less a no-op because it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I also got a `input` search which filters and searches the whole table which worked almost the same but checked `.indexOf(inputValue) > -1` instead. My first thoughts were that I could do something similar but for one column, apparently not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter table rows with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951014/filter-table-rows-with-jquery)

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Table and table's contents are generated through an Ajax call. However if **really** needed I could provide an example...

Comment: @Andreas I'll fiddle around some more, your linked question lead me closer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `.indexOf()` to match the column with the string. I then hid the parents and to reset the visibility I show all `tr` (excluding th) inside the `.filter()` function.

I implemented it like this:

```
$('#res_btn').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('td:nth-child(1)').filter(function() {
        $('tr:not(:has(th))').show();
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value);
    }).parent().hide();
});
```

Thanks to [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) who linked to a similar question.